# sed exclamation marks

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

Today I've come across this command for extracting domain name from domain controller's FQDN:

```
DOMAIN_NAME=$(echo $DC_PC | sed -r 's!^[^.]+\.!!')
```

What is the meaning of these exclamation marks in sed? How does it work?

Comment: That is called as **Delimiter** in `sed`

Comment: Or just `domain_name=${DC_PC#*.}` (strictly speaking the equivalent would be `${DC_PC#[!.]*.}` because of that `+` which is I don't think was intended) which would be a lot more portable, efficient and reliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first character after `s` is used as the separator for the parameters to `s`, so this replaces anything matching `^[^.]+\.` with the empty string. Traditionally this would be written

```
sed -r 's/^[^.]+\.//'
```

Comment: The reason to change the delimiter is to prevent the leaning toothpick problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome#Sed